# Responsive menu Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a menu for my project. In my page I created two div tag. One is for logo another one is for menu. If I am shrinking my browser window screen, the menu need to come under the logo. I tried in bootstrap. But it is coming partially. Here is my [menubar](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3ywv/show/). What I am doing wrong. I need help.

```
<div id="123A" style="float: left; text-align: center;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; position:absolute; z-index:1;">
<img src="img/Logo_Transparent_200.png"  width="150" height="35"/>
<span id="fcolor"> MR POOL</span>
</div> 


<div id="123B" style="text-align: center; position:absolute; z-index:1; ">
   <nav id="na">
   <ul>
   <li id="na1" ><a href="#">Pool Vessel Details &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/arrow2.gif"/></a>
    <ul id="content1" >
      <table>
      <tr><td>
      <li><a href="#">Fleet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pool Points</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OffHire</a></li>                                  
      </td> 
      <td>      
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" style="width:200px; height:175px;" />                                         
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
   </ul>
  </li>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look at the source on the example you want and see how it is done. if you post a question here people aren't just going to do it for you.

Comment: I think the reason is the second div didn't set the min-width. if the div set this css, the position of menu will not change.